# Reading the contents of a .txt file into columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-columns

I have a text file with customer names and ID numbers stored in the following format:

```
<p>Name</p> 
<p>ID Number</p> 
<p>Name</p>
<p>ID Number</p> 
<p>Name</p>
<p>ID Number......</p>
```

Is there a way in python to read the contents of the file and output into 2 columns like below:

```
Name     IDNumber
```

Comment: This is definitely doable. What have you tried so far? You will get best results on Stack Overflow by posting an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
def col():
    sample= open("members.txt","r")
    found=sample.read().splitlines()
    Name=found[::2]
    ID=found[1::2]
    for c1, c2 in zip(Name, ID):
        print (("%-9s %s") % (c1, c2))
```